# Pausing entire container when concurrency is greater than 1

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When we are using a container with concurrency greater than 1, and wish to pause all the child containers, can we pause directly using:

```
MessageListenerContainer mlc= registry.getListenerContainer(<id>);
mlc.pause();
```

Or do we have to cast it to a Concurrent Message Listener Container and pause each container individually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `@KafkaListener(id = "your-id",...)` for your method, it will be registered as an instance of `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`. So when you call `mlc.pause()`, it actually is `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer#pause`, you **don't** have to cast it (polymorphism).

With `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer#pause`, it will delegate to all `KafkaMessageListenerContainer#pause`s inside it (for example: concurrency = 3, you will have 3 instances of `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`). **You don't have to pause each container individually,** `mlc.pause()` is enough.